# Converting vectors to matrix

Tags: java

First of all,here is my code

Matrix class;

```
public class Matrix {
double[][] myArray = new double[4][4];

public Matrix(double myArray[][]){
    this.myArray=myArray;
   }
}

package p1;

public class Vector {
      double []yourArray;
public Vector(double... yourArray) {
        this.yourArray = yourArray;
      }
    }

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Vector myVector = new Vector(1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0);

    double[] myArray = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0};
    Vector myVector2 = new Vector(myArray);
    }
}
```

I have some instructions to do;

Constructors: write three constructors

(1) Taking a two dimensional array and setting it as the matrix.

(2) Taking a list of  of  vectors as  comma seperated argument list and converting these vectors from the first to the last to a matrix(Vector is another class to be explained below) and constructing a matrix from these vectors either creating them as columns or raws of the matrix determined by another parameter.(if 0 treat them as raw vectors , if 1 treat these vectors as columns of the matrix)

(3) Taking an integer and producing an Identity matrix of dimension determined by that integer.

I did first one but in the second one,i cannot transfer code from vector class

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    public Matrix(Vector... vectors) {
        myArray = new double[vectors.length][];
        for (int i = 0; i < vectors.length; ++i) {
            double[] a = vectors[i].yourArray;
            myArray[i] = Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length);
        }
    }
```

Comment: why do you use 'Arrays' here ?

Comment: If you don't copy an array, it will be shared by Vector and Matrix.  When you change an element of Vector , corresponding element of Matrix will be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Use nested for loops.

```
public class Vector{
    private double array[];
    public Vector(double array[]){
        this.array = array;
    }
    public int length(){
        return this.array.length;
    }
    public double get(int i){
        return array[i];
    }
}


public class Matrix{
    private double matrix[][];
    public Matrix(int length){
        this.matrix = new double[length][length];
        for(int i=0; i<length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<length; j++){
                if(i==j)
                    this.matrix[i][j] = 1;
                else
                    this.matrix[i][j] = 0;
            }   
        }
    }
    public Matrix(int type,Vector...vectors){
        if(type == 1)
            this.matrix = new double[vectors.length][vectors[0].length()];
        else
            this.matrix = new double[vectors[0].length()][vectors.length];

        for(int i=0; i<vectors.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<vectors[i].length(); j++){
                if(type == 1)
                    this.matrix[i][j] = vectors[i].get(j);
                else
                    this.matrix[j][i] = vectors[i].get(j);
            }
        }
    }
    public double get(int i, int j){
        return matrix[i][j];
    }
}
```